# Dropdown Listbox in iphone

Tags: iphone

How we can perfectly achieve dropdwn listbox in iphone...And instead for this I want if suppose i pressed button then it will display the UITableView or UIGestureView or UIPickerVIew....

Which one is more suitable instead for dropdown listbox.....
please help my question.....

Comment: https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a pickerview for relatively small number of list items and would prefer a table with a searchbar and a checkbutton accessory for a huge list.

Comment: Thanks for your help....but what about UIGestureView.....I think its look like best.....please send your reply..

Comment: Did you actually read about the so called UIGestureView? Please do the reading first

Comment: @BoltClock: he must have read some tutorial with a custom class inheriting from one of the standard view controllers and probably thinks its built-in

Comment: k thanks for your clear idea....it is a UIPinchGestureRecognizer...sorry i am new to iphone....it is my mistake...